# Django: view tracking data with tens-of-thousands of views per day

Tags: python, django, postgresql, bigdata, analytics

I have a Django app with a Postgres backend. Users can make posts and view them.

"Views" sit around the high-tens-of-thousands to 100K+ per day total. We want to track views so that we can filter out posts users have already seen from their home timeline. In the future, this will also be used for algorithmically surfacing content to users better.

My original thought was to store these views as rows in the database as another table:

```
class PostView(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

However this would quickly overwhelm the database with hundreds of thousands (or millions) of extra rows in weeks, (which I believe would overwhelm the database? Would or slow it down)?

Is there perhaps another way that people typically store this sort of view data? Or is my approach effectively fine?

Comment: millions is not very much.  You should have a plan for how long you need/want to keep them and (maybe) a partitioning strategy which makes that plan easier to implement.

Comment: @jjanes Sounds like my approach should be fine for now?

Comment: Fine for now, yes.  But partitioning is hard to implement retroactively.